# is there a shortcut key in vs.net 2022 for git push or sync?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, git-push

is there a shortcut key in vs.net 2022 for git push or git push and pull (i.e. sync)?

Answer (score 1):

finally I decided to set a brand new shortcut for myself. Ctrl-0-P :-)